# Writing a factorial function in C

Tags: c, factorial

My superficial implementation of the factorial function fails generally for number greater then 16.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int x){
  if (x==1)
    return 1;
  else
    return (x* fact(x-1));

}
int main() {
  int x;
  scanf("%d", &x);
  printf("%d\n", fact(x));
  
}
```

Does this depend on the fact that at a certain point of the recursion the integers will not be representable according to `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: What results do you expect for values greater than 16? And what is the size of your integers on your machine? The answer is probably that you are right and your integers are too small.

Comment: it's simply because `fact(16) > MAX_INT`, `MAX_INT = 2147483647` - `fact(16) = 20922789888000` (source: wikipedia)

Comment: All types in C have limited ranged. On most systems `int` is a signed 32-bit integer type, with a range from approximately minus two billion to plus two billion. If you want numbers larger than plus two billion then using `int` you will have *arithmetic overflow* which leads to *undefined behavior*. Use larger types like e.g. `uint64_t` (which is an unsigned 64-bit integer type) if available.

Comment: @Some programmer dude, I believe `sizeof(int)` is compiler dependent and usually is the fastest integer type _(for integer operations)_ for the platform... So if your compiler supports 64bit operating systems then its size should be 8 bytes.

Comment: @WENDYN Having a 64bit system does not mean that `int` is 64 bit. You can also have 64bit pointers and 32bit `int`.

Comment: `uint64_t` will help a bit, up to `20!`.

Comment: @WENDYN While technically true, but still there are no popular PC-like systems where `sizeof(int)` is anything else than `4`. Even on 64-bit systems. The `int` type no longer is coupled to the native "word" size of the target CPU, it's just a "general integer type".

Comment: *Does this depend on the fact that at a certain point of the recursion the integers will not be representable according to `sizeof(int)`?* Yes.

Answer (score 3):

> Does this depend on the fact that at a certain point of the recursion the integers will not be representable according to sizeof(int)?

Yup.  Factorials get *very* large *very* fast and will exceed the range of the native integer types for *N* > 20.  To compute anything beyond `20!` you will need to use an arbitrary precision math library like [GNU GMP](https://gmplib.org/):

```
#include <gmp.h>
...
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
{
  mpz_t result;
  mpz_fac_ui( result, i );
  gmp_printf( "%3u! = %Zd\n", i, result );
}
```

As an aside, while the *definition* of a factorial is recursive - *N! = N * (N-1)!, 0! = 1* - it's better solved using an iterative algorithm like

```
unsigned long fac( unsigned long n )
{
  unsigned long ret = 1;
  while( n )
    ret *= n--;
  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So on your average system an `int` represents 4 bytes.

The maximum signed number representable with this is `2147483647`.
Values greater than factorial 12 exceed this number, so it won't be able to be stored in 4 bytes.

The fact that it worked up until factorial 16 may indicate that your `int` represents 6-bytes, which would be rare.

You can choose to take a `long`, `long long` or `unsigned` data type which typically allow you to store larger positive numbers.

Answer (score 1):

More or less but, the limit should not be 16.

When integers are 32 bits large, the highest representable factorial is

```
fact(12) = 479001600 = 0x1c8cfc00
```

(next would be `fact(13) = 6227020800 = 0x17328cc00`)

And for 64 bits integers, the highest representable factorial is

```
fact(20) = 2432902008176640000 = 0x21c3677c82b40000
```

(next would be `fact(21) = 51090942171709440000 = 0x2c5077d36b8c40000`)

---

16 should be the limit only on a 48 bits system (6 bytes) which AFAIK is uncommon...

Answer (score 0):

As John Bode aptly said in his answer, factorials get *very* large *very* fast.
Here's more or less the full story:

```
 1! = 1
 2! = 2
 3! = 6
 4! = 24
 5! = 120
 6! = 720
 7! = 5040                  largest factorial representable as a signed 16-bit int
 8! = 40320                 largest factorial representable as an unsigned 16-bit int
 9! = 362880
10! = 3628800
11! = 39916800
12! = 479001600             largest factorial representable as a 32-bit int
13! = 6227020800
14! = 87178291200
15! = 1307674368000
16! = 20922789888000
17! = 355687428096000
18! = 6402373705728000
19! = 121645100408832000
20! = 2432902008176640000   largest factorial representable as a 64-bit int
21! = 51090942171709440000
22! = 1124000727777607680000
23! = 25852016738884976640000
24! = 620448401733239439360000
25! = 15511210043330985984000000
26! = 403291461126605635584000000
27! = 10888869450418352160768000000
28! = 304888344611713860501504000000
29! = 8841761993739701954543616000000
30! = 265252859812191058636308480000000
31! = 8222838654177922817725562880000000
32! = 263130836933693530167218012160000000
33! = 8683317618811886495518194401280000000
34! = 295232799039604140847618609643520000000   largest representable in 128 bits
35! = 10333147966386144929666651337523200000000
36! = 371993326789901217467999448150835200000000
37! = 13763753091226345046315979581580902400000000
38! = 523022617466601111760007224100074291200000000
39! = 20397882081197443358640281739902897356800000000
40! = 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000
41! = 33452526613163807108170062053440751665152000000000
42! = 1405006117752879898543142606244511569936384000000000
43! = 60415263063373835637355132068513997507264512000000000
44! = 2658271574788448768043625811014615890319638528000000000
45! = 119622220865480194561963161495657715064383733760000000000
46! = 5502622159812088949850305428800254892961651752960000000000
47! = 258623241511168180642964355153611979969197632389120000000000
48! = 12413915592536072670862289047373375038521486354677760000000000
49! = 608281864034267560872252163321295376887552831379210240000000000
50! = 30414093201713378043612608166064768844377641568960512000000000000
```

See also [http://catb.org/~esr/jargon/html/B/bignum.html](http://catb.org/%7Eesr/jargon/html/B/bignum.html) .

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h> 

unsigned int factorial(unsigned int n) 
{ 
    if (n == 0) 
        return 1; 
    return n * factorial(n - 1); 
} 

int main() 
{ 
    int num = 5; 
    printf("Factorial of %d is %d", 

           num, factorial(num)); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?